# Linkedin API, Company Updates, Select Language

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Hi i am trying to get company updates from linkedin api. But the problem is i am getting company updates in all languages. I only want to get english updates. My question is how do i get only english updates. Below is my code

```
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/"+CompanyLinkedinID+"/updates?event-type=status-update&oauth2_access_token="+user.LinkedinOauth2Token
lp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
doc = etree.parse(lp)
lp.close()
```

After these four lines of code i just parse these updates. How do i set the parameter to get only English updates.

Comment: I have not found any solution yet...

Comment: Can you start a bounty on this question? That would draw more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any satisfactory answer. SO below is the approach i took.
Once i receive the update i used python library "guess_language" to detect which language the update belongs to. This library works on trigram
https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language
It gave satisfactory results.